# Installing PCL on Anaconda (Windows)?

Tags: python, pip, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to install PCL based on https://anaconda.org/ccordoba12/repo
However I received these messages:

For python-PCL:

`UnsatisfiableError: The following secificaitons were found to be in conflict:
- python 3.5*
- python-pcl 0.2*`

For PCL:

`PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
- python-pcl 1.7.2*`

I'm using Anaconda3 4.3.1 and Python 3.5.2. I use these versions because I will work also with TensorFlow.

So what could I do?

Comment: Could you add the `conda` commands that lead to the error messages?

Comment: Sure:
`conda install -c ccordoba12 python-pcl=0.2` and 
`conda install -c ccordoba12 pcl=1.7.2`